# How to know in VI which line the cursor is on?

Tags: linux, vim, copy, copy-paste, vi

I want to copy paste some lines in `vi`.

I have a text like

```
python class1 def:
   code code code
   ...
   code code code
   last line class1

python class2 def:
   code code code
   ...
   code code code
```

I want to copy the whole `class1`. I was trying to do it with `yNy`, so I needed to get `N`, that is, to count the number of lines the class has.

Then I thought it would be good to get the line number of `python class1 def:` (let's say X) and the `last line class1` (Y), calculate `N=Y-X`, go to the first line of the class and do the `yNy`. However, I could not figure out how I can get the line numbers.

So, is there any way to know which line I am in? And in general, is there any other way to copy paste a whole block like the one I indicated?

This is my `vi` version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 26 2012 16:44:45)
Included patches: 1-547
```

Comment: Try pressing `Ctrl-g` on a given line.  Actually that gives much more details than `:.=`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The current line number can be obtained by `:.=`.  `Ctrl-g` gives more details including filename, column information, ...

In order to copy a block, go to the start of the line to be copied `0`.  Hitting `v` would start the visual mode.  Navigate to the last line to be copied.  Yank `y`.  (Visual selection is now in buffer.)

Answer (score 7):

- Using only normal mode commands:

  You can do `y}` to yank everything from the current line to and including the next empty line, delimiting what Vim considers to be a "paragraph". This may or may not work depending on your coding style.

  Still using the notion of "paragraph", you can do `yip` or `yap` from anywhere in a "paragraph".

  You can set the `number` option which allows you to see absolute line numbers and therefore be able to do `y10G`, "yank everything from here to line 10".

  You can set the `relativenumber` option which allows you to see relative line numbers and therefore be able to do `y5j`, "yank everything from here to 5 lines below".

  You can do `V/foo<CR>y` to yank everything from here to `foo` linewise.

  More generally, you can simply use visual mode to select what you want and yank it.

  You can also set a mark on the first line of the class with `ma`, move the cursor to its last line and do `y'a` (which sounds like the name of a Lovecraftian deity).
- Using Ex commands:

  Because the aforementioned `number` option shows absolute line numbers, you can see that the class ends at line 10 and do `:.,10y`.

  Because the aforementioned `relativenumber` option shows relative line numbers, you can see that the class ends 5 line below and do `:,+5y` (dropping the implied `.`).
- Using your statusline (or not):

  You can `:set ruler` to have the current line number displayed on the right side of your statusbar if you have one or on the right side of your command line if you don't have a statusline.
- Using Vimscript:

  You can use `line('.')` to retrieve the number of the current line.
- Using custom text-objects:

  There are a number of custom text-objects available on vim.org for indented blocks, function arguments and many other things. Maybe there is one for Python classes.

More generally, I'd advise you to set either `ruler`, `number` or `relativenumber` permanently in your `~/.vimrc` and get used to it.

- `ruler` is the least invasive of the bunch but it's also the most limited: you know where you are but it doesn't help at all when you want to define a target.
- `number` is the most classical and can be used to easily target a specific line.
- `relativenumber` is a bit weird at first and, like `number`, can be used easily to target a specific line.

Choosing `number` or `relativenumber` is, as far as I'm concerned, a matter of taste. I find `relativenumber` very intuitive, YMMV.

Comment: Great! `y}` worked perfectly for Python purposes. The one I could not use properly is *You can `:set number` and do `y10G`*. I get a *"E488: Trailing characters"* error. Also, I would add `:set nonu` to exit the `:set number` mode. Thank you for such a comprehensive explanation

Comment: Those are two separated commands: `:set number` enables the display of absolute line numbers and `y10G` is another command that yanks "from here to line 10". `:set nu` and `:set rnu` are used only to activate line numbers and not meant at all to be typed each time you want to yank multiple lines. That would be crazily inneficient! Just add either one or the other setting in your `~/.vimrc` and enjoy.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following in command mode

1. `:.=` returns line number of current line at bottom of screen
2. `yNy` or `Nyy` copies the next N lines, including the current line
3. `p` pastes the copied text after the current line

Additionally,

`:set nu!` in command mode will turn on/off the line number at the beginning of each line.

Comment: Thanks! `:.=` is fine for this purpose. Another answer also suggested the `Ctrl-g` option to get more info.

Answer (score 1):

let the vim registers do this task. why bother calculating lines

for example if you want to copy line X to line y

1) move your cursor to 1st character of line X.

2) type "ma" . this will save current cursor position in register "a".

3) move cursor to last char of line Y.

4) type "y`a". copy is done

5) p pastes the copied text

This method can work not only lines but block ,words even on characters.

Comment: Excellent! I did not know about this registering method. I also fixed the format in your code, just tiny things. Thanks!

Comment: if you want to copy linex to line y just do `:xty`

Comment: Thanks, @Kent. What I get is just the `x` line copied.

Comment: @fedorqui yep, x, y are two line numbers. :) maybe I misunderstood the point.